# BlackBerry App world not able to download application in draft mode

Tags: blackberry, in-app-purchase

I am trying to create  BB application that features the in-app purchase. I followed the following steps and was expecting the result.

1. Setup a 'sandbox' account in using the BlackBerry App World vendor portal
2. Upload your app into BlackBerry App world but don't publish it, just leave it in draft state
3. Also in the vendor portal, set up your digital goods (the things available for in-app purchase)
4. On your BlackBerry, load App World and login with your sandbox account email address.
5. Within any screen in App World press ALT+TST and enter the SKU or ID of your test app.
6. You can then download the test version of your app (which is not available to anyone else)
7. Once the app is downloaded and installed you will be able to test your in app payments.

For me it worked fine for some time but from last two days when I am trying to download the app using the step 5 i.e. ALT+TST after the download starts it stops giving an error "An error has occurred, please try again later"

Please let me know what can be the possible problem.

Comment: you implemented the in app payment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. I have some assumption in this regards. It seems when you upload a build to vendor portal, it takes time to get ready to be downloaded. The time may vary from 7-12 hours. They take some to update their database and synchronize. 
Another thing what you can try is that set your timezone and time to be automatically updated by carrier.

RIM confirmed this is bug in App World ver 3.0 however it seems in version 3.1 it is still persisting

Hope this solves your issue.