# How to install a draft app on a blackberry sandboxed account

Tags: blackberry, sandbox, blackberry-10

I have uploaded an app on Blackberry World, in draft mode, added my account to the sandbox section, but how do I install the app on my device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those instructions are for BBOS, not BB10.

For BB10, you need to turn on Development Mode on your device from the device Settings.

Then open BlackBerry World, open the application menu, choose Settings > Development Mode.

Enter your SKU or BlackBerry World content ID, hit Test Content.

It should open to the details page of your App.

(I think it can take a couple hours after posting an App in draft mode before its available in Sandbox mode.)

Comment: It was available for me right away after uploading it to AppWorld

Answer (score 3):

**1**.On your BlackBerry Device, load App World and login with your sandbox account email address.

**2**.Within any screen in App World press ALT+TST and enter the SKU or ID of your test app.

**3**.You can then download the test version of your app (which is not available to anyone else).
Once the app is downloaded and installed you will be able to test it.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120132/blackberry-app-world-not-able-to-download-application-in-draft-mode)

Comment: Some more information: your device need to be in Development mode. Regarding step 2, on a full-touch device, you'll need to go in the Settings menu, where you'll have a Development entry. There you can enter the SKU.